# How do I make a conditional editableCellTemplate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to make certain rows in ui grid be dropdown menus. to accomplish this; I set editableCellTemplate to this;

```
<div ng-if="!row.entity.dropdown">
  <form
    name="inputForm">
    <input
      type="text"
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
      ui-grid-editor
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" />
  </form>
</div>
<div ng-if="row.entity.dropdown">
  <form
    name="inputForm">
    <select
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
      ui-grid-edit-dropdown
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"
      ng-options="field[editDropdownIdLabel] as field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray">
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

I then attach 'true' to each row.entity that I want to be a dropdown. However, with this code endCellEdit does not appear to fire when I select a different cell in the grid with my mouse. If I replace the ng-if with ng-show, selecting a different cell does trigger endCellEdit, but the non dropdown cells are effectively not editable as the cell stops editing almost immediately after the cell is selected, removing the editable template. I don't care which method I have to use, but I need both types of cells to be editable and for switching to a different cell to trigger endCellEdit. How could I go about this?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Someone has the idea why above won't work and if it is even possible to achieve?